# Bluetooth Receiver Board - Noise Problem

Tags: noise, bluetooth, board

I recently bought a bluetooth receiver board in order to add bluetooth to my car, this however is not as easy as I thought. I am not very skilled with electronics.
I have an aux audio input in my car so all I needed to do was connect a minijack cable to the bluetooth board, but when I do this there is a lot of noise. Other than the noise, the sound is very good. I have checked that the connection is correct in terms of which wires in the jack cable is which (yellow = gnd, red = right, white = left)
I'm not sure if the problem is a ground loop or something like that.

Please help :)

I have connected my jack like this: 
[image: Minijack cable connection to bluetooth board]

Bluetooth Board: 
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07N8N21M1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: what exactly is a "bluetooth receiver board"?

Comment: That appears designed to drive speakers, not another amplifier.  You could try a series coupling capacitor but it may never work well. Questions on the *usage* of products are off topic here, and that includes *undocumented* modules and car audio systems...